# C++ For Loop not Exiting

Tags: c++, for-loop, break

I have a for loop, a very simple one, in my program, and I want it to loop through and do something for some minimum number of times. However, the loop simply...stops. But does not move on to the next thing in the program. For instance, when min is 9, it runs for i=0 to i=8, then freezes. It should exit the for loop, but it does not execute the next print instruction, nor does it execute the loop again. It just stops. The program hangs, doing absolutely nothing as far as I can tell. I don't understand why this is.

The merged.put() function I want to execute just puts x or y in merged, depending on the condition. That part works. This is just a small part of a much larger program. sp1, sp2, and merged are all defined elsewhere.

```
int i;
    int x;
    int y;
    for(i=0; i < min; i++)
    {
        cout << " here " + convert(i);
        x = sp1.get_num(i);
        y = sp2.get_num(i);
        if(x >= y) {
            merged.put(x);
        }
        else {
            merged.put(y);
        }
        cout << " end" << endl;
    }
cout << "out";
```

EDIT: I'm not posting the entire code, it's several hundred lines long. Type of min is int. The reply down there was helpful, when << endl was added to the last print statement, it printed. My problem now appears to be here, getting stuck on the second while, because I was not incrementing i. Shame on me...thanks for the help. (This comes directly after the above code)

```
if (sp_large == 2) {
        cout << "1" << endl;;
        while (i < sp2.get_size()) {
            merged.put(sp2.get_num(i));
        }
    }
    else {
        while (i < sp1.get_size()) {
            merged.put(sp1.get_num(i));
        }   
        cout << "2" << endl;
    }
```

EDIT: Problem solved, thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem lies in the code you posted? It seems like the problem comes later, but you don't get to see the "out" message because it isn't flushed out before whatever comes next hangs. Add `<< endl`  to your second print and try your code again.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code, so try to eliminate the suspects: Comment out the calls to get_num and/or merged and assign values to x and y directly. Does that change anything? If so, we need to investigate what happends in those calls.

Comment: Can you please include the entire function's code, and any possible warnings the compiler may produce.

Comment: What comes after `count << "out";`? Perhaps the program is hanging there (and the "out" is waiting in a buffer somewhere).

Comment: may be `sp1.get_num(i)` or `sp1.get_num(i)` throws an exception when i=8, debug it.

Comment: The type of min, please. If it is anything more then int, the loop can legitimately be infinite.

Answer (score 9):

I'm betting that it's actually a later part of the program that is hanging.

This line:

```
cout << "out";
```

just puts "out" on the output-buffer, and won't actually print "out" until the output-buffer gets flushed. (Which *could* happen immediately, but is not likely to.) Change that line to this:

```
cout << "out" << endl;
```

and "out" will be printed as soon as that line is run. This will help you figure out if the program is hanging before it gets to that line, or somewhere later on.

Comment: If is so it's a bug in c++ runtime and I don't think so.

Comment: It's not a bug in the runtime, that's just how buffered output works. +1

Comment: He's right, when I added the endl it printed. I'm working on trying to narrow the problem down again. I didn't know buffered output worked that way.

Comment: Use `std:flush` instead of `std::endl` if you don't want a newline.

Comment: If you use std::cerr you don't need to flush as the error stream is not buffered (because when you are debugging you want to know everything that was printed).